# How are c++ class instance members handed at the machine level?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I understand the basic layout (given a typical c++ implementation) of class instance members, but say you have MyClass with int num as a member, and you create an instance of it, how is the specific address of the member in memory handled at run time?
I'll be clearer with an example:

```
class MyClass
    {
      int num;
      int num2;
      int num3;
    public:
      void setNum(); //always sets num to 10
    };
```

Then you call setnum, how does it know what memory to set to 10?
The memory layout for MyClass might look like

```
class MyClass size(12):
        +---
     0  | num
     4  | num1
     8  | num2
        +---
```

So is it as simple as when setNum gets called with the hidden pointer to your instance of myclass for member access it gets written based on offest? forexample myclasspointer+4?

EDIT clarification how does it decide where to write to? failed copypaste left the vftable in there. I totally imagine its gonna just be a known offset right?

Or is it something more complex?

Apologizing for unclear terminallogy I rarely know how to phrase a question right...

Comment: If you have no `virtual` functions, there is no vtable pointer. `sizeof(MyClass) == sizeof(int)` in any reasonable implementation.

Comment: @delnan my bad, edited out and clarified question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will know the contents of the `class` (or `struct`), and most importantly the offsets of the different member variables. the `setNum` function is given a `this` pointer as a "hidden" argument, and the compiler will take the `this` variable and add the offset for `num`.

Exactly how this happens depends on the compiler. In LLVM, it would use a `getelementptr` VM instruction, which understands the structure and, given a base-address, adds the offset given by the index. This will then translate to some sort of instruction that takes the `this` and either a direct offset addition in a single instruction, or two instructions to load the pointer and then add the offset - depending a little bit on the architecture, and what the next instructions "need".

Since the `num` member is the first member in the struct, it will be zero, so on x86-64, compiled with clang++ -O1, we get this disassembly:

```
_ZN7MyClass6setNumEv:                   # @_ZN7MyClass6setNumEv
    movl    $10, (%rdi)
    retq
```

In other words, move the number 10 into the address of `this` (in `%rdi` - first argument on a Linux machine).

The LLVM IR shows better what goes on:

```
%class.MyClass = type { i32, i32, i32 }

; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define void @_ZN7MyClass6setNumEv(%class.MyClass* nocapture %this) #0 align 2 {
entry:
  %num = getelementptr inbounds %class.MyClass* %this, i64 0, i32 0
  store i32 10, i32* %num, align 4, !tbaa !1
  ret void
}
```

The class contains 3 `i32` (32 bit integers), and the function takes a `this` pointer, it then uses `getelementptr` to get the first element (element 0). Yes, there's one more argument than you'd expect. That's how LLVM works ;)

Then a store instruction for the value 10 into the `%num` calculated address.

If we change the code in `setNum` so that it stores 10 into `num2` instead, we get:

```
define void @_ZN7MyClass6setNumEv(%class.MyClass* nocapture %this) #0 align 2 {
entry:
  %num2 = getelementptr inbounds %class.MyClass* %this, i64 0, i32 2
  store i32 10, i32* %num2, align 4, !tbaa !1
  ret void
}
```

Note the change of the last number into `getelementptr`.

As assembly code it becomes:

```
_ZN7MyClass6setNumEv:                   # @_ZN7MyClass6setNumEv
    movl    $10, 8(%rdi)
    retq
```

(As it currently stands, in Revision 2 of the original question, your class MyClass has a size of 12, 3 * 4 bytes, not 8 like your text says).

Comment: Excellent answer and thanks for pointing out the error! That makes excellent sense

Comment: +1 A detailed article disguised as an answer! Thanks.